# How to add select in my Include with a theninclude

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to get info from 3 tables, Clients, invoices, and transactions. Every client can have many invoices, and every invoice can have many transactions.

There are several hundreds of thousands of the invoices and transactions with quite a few columns on each table. I only need a few of the columns and would take too long to grab all columns on all the tables.

Here's what I'm attempting to do, but it does not work.

```
var Clients = cps.Clients
    .Include(q => q.Invoices.Select(x=> new TInvoices
    {
        Invno = x.Invno,
        // more columns...
    })
        .ThenInclude(q => q.Transactions).ToList();
```

I'd also like to do a select on the transactions as well.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

I was going to try some linq joins and such, but I have limited knowledge and understanding of that area. Open to suggestions or ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: .Include().ThenInclude().Select()...move your select out of the first include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select` instead of `Include`. `Include` always loads whole record and there is no way to do something else.

```cs
var Clients = cps.Clients
    .Select(c => new // or other concrete type
    {
        c.id,
        // other properties

        Invoices = c.Invoices.Select(i => new TInvoices
        {
            Invno = i.Invno,
            // more columns...

            Transations = i.Transactions.ToList()
        })
        .ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Is there a faster way of pulling the information? I have about 9k clients, 200k invoices, and over 500K transactions. it takes about 2.5 seconds just pulling the id's of each table. Thanks!

Comment: Add `AsSplitQuery()` to LINQ query. Also consider to do not load whole database, it has no sense.

Comment: The AsSplitQuery() does not exist and I can't find anywhere online that has had this issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: `AsSplitQuery` is introduced in EF Core 5. Which ORM version do you use?